# Getting the column name of a specific data with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy 0.8 and I want to get the column name of the input only, not all the column in the table.

here is the code:

```
rec = raw_input("Enter keyword to search: ")
res = session.query(test.__table__).filter(test.fname == rec).first()

data = ','.join(map(str, res)) +","
print data

#saw this here @ SO but not the one I wanted. It displays all of the columns
columns = [m.key for m in data.columns]
print columns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just query for the columns you want. Like if you had some model `MyModel`
You can do:

```
session.query(MyModel.wanted_column1, ...) ...  # rest of the query
```

This would only select all the columns mentioned there.

You can use the [select](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#selecting) syntax.

Or if you still want the model object to be returned and certain columns not loaded, you can use [deferred column loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#deferred).